# Intel 3160 wireless network card connect to wifi will break down for a while

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, dell, lts

My laptop is a Dell inspiron 15 5000.

My Operating System is Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

`lspci` shows that the wireless network card is an `Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)`.

I found that when I connect to WiFi, the WiFi will break down. Then for while it works fine again.

I don't know whether it's because of the network card or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it happened in my new laptop as well. Try updating the kernel to 4.11 or 4.12.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12/

Download depending upon your OS type i.e (64-bit/amd64 or 32-bit/i386):

```
    linux-headers-4.12.0-xxxxxx_all.deb
    linux-headers-4.12.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
    linux-image-4.12.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
```

Install by the following command

```
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This will install the latest kernel files. Restart ubuntu for changes to take effect.

Comment: my kernel version is `v4.10` , so do I need to update?

Comment: mine was also v4.10 but causing wifi issues on 2 of my 7th gen laptops. upgrading to 4.11 worked for me. You can always rollback if it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe use a gui tool like ukuu www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html

Comment: thanks , Now I have update the kernal to v4.12, I'll have a test.

Comment: No problem. My first answer accepted. Feels quite an achievement.

Comment: I found that afeter I update the kernal, my docker damon can't be run, I feel so sad.